# zip file is not generating in the given path

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my get_status function which is inside the controller. I am trying to generate zip fle in the given path '/var/www/html/hdfcdsademo/uploadpdf/'.$this->session->userdata("product_type").'/'.

```
public function get_status(){

    $query=$this->db->query("select (select COUNT(DISTINCT(dsahubwise)) FROM month_3_lap where isgenerated=0 && product_pre='".$this->session->userdata("product_type")."') as pending,(select COUNT(DISTINCT(dsahubwise)) FROM month_3_lap where isgenerated=1 && product_pre='".$this->session->userdata("product_type")."') as generate");
    $result=$query->row();
    if($result->pending==0){
    $this->generatepdf_model->createZipFromDir('/var/www/html/hdfcdsademo/uploadpdf/'.$this->session->userdata("product_type").'/','/var/www/html/hdfcdsademo/uploadpdf/'.$this->session->userdata("product_type").'/LAP_DSA.zip');
        $this->db->query("UPDATE generatepdf SET isgenerate=0,is_archive=1 where product_pre='".$this->session->userdata("product_type")."'");
    }
    echo json_encode(['pending'=>$result->pending,'generate'=>$result->generate]);
}
```

This is my createZipFromDir function inside the model.

```
public function createZipFromDir($dir, $zip_file) {
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if (true !== $zip->open($zip_file, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE)) {

        return false;
    }
    $this->zipDir($dir, $zip);

    return $zip;
}
public function zipDir($dir, $zip, $relative_path = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) {
    $dir = rtrim($dir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file === '.' || $file === '..') {
                continue;
            }
            if (is_file($dir . $file)) {
                $zip->addFile($dir . $file, $file);
            } elseif (is_dir($dir . $file)) {
                $this->zipDir($dir . $file, $zip, $relative_path . $file);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: Do you recieve any error?

Answer (score 0):

Before uploading a file to a directory, you have to create the directory on server:

```
public function get_status(){

     $query=$this->db->query("select (select COUNT(DISTINCT(dsahubwise)) FROM month_3_lap where isgenerated=0 && product_pre='".$this->session->userdata("product_type")."') as pending,(select COUNT(DISTINCT(dsahubwise)) FROM month_3_lap where isgenerated=1 && product_pre='".$this->session->userdata("product_type")."') as generate");
     $result=$query->row();
     if($result->pending==0){
          $dir='/var/www/html/hdfcdsademo/uploadpdf/'.$this->session->userdata("product_type");
          if (!file_exists($dir)) {
              mkdir($baseDir, 0777, true);
          }
          $this->generatepdf_model->createZipFromDir('/var/www/html/hdfcdsademo/uploadpdf/'.$this->session->userdata("product_type").'/','/var/www/html/hdfcdsademo/uploadpdf/'.$this->session->userdata("product_type").'/LAP_DSA.zip');
          $this->db->query("UPDATE generatepdf SET isgenerate=0,is_archive=1 where product_pre='".$this->session->userdata("product_type")."'");
     }
     echo json_encode(['pending'=>$result->pending,'generate'=>$result->generate]);
}
```